# php - single page login form (form+validation) not working properly

Tags: php, authentication

I try myself a single page login (form + validation). It works slightly good. I'm using `SESSION` for checking all the conditions (for whether user exists, password correct or not).

My code here:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
   header("Location:member_page.php");
}
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['result']))
    {
       if($_SESSION['result']=="false")
              echo "<font color=white>Invalid Credentials. Try again!!! </font>";
       if($_SESSION['result']=="false1")
               echo "<font color=white>User doesn't exist. Try again!!!</font>";
    }
}
else
{
/* check user Authentication in DB*/    
}
```

It works good. But When i reload the page, the session remains exist, so same error is showing in the page. I think this may be annoying to the Users. IS there any modifications can be made in this code to solve this?
Also tell me whether this code is good for single page login form?

Comment: Your question needs a bounty, wait untill tomrrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you echo out the error you need to remove the variable from the session.

Add `unset($_SESSION['result']);` under:

```
if($_SESSION['result']=="false") 
    echo "<font color=white>Invalid Credentials. Try again!!! </font>";
if($_SESSION['result']=="false1") 
    echo "<font color=white>User doesn't exist. Try again!!!</font>";
```

Comment: Awesome... Thank you so much.. Tried this..It  Works Awesomely.